# Google Map Flutter: Polygon, Circle and Marker

Tags: flutter, google-maps-markers, polygon, google-maps-flutter

**How to draw polygons on top of markers in Flutter?** [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVyXS.png).
I am building a mobile application using `google_map_flutter` to display markers and draw polygons on it. I'm facing an issue where the drawn polygons are appearing beneath the markers, making it difficult to draw the polygons effectively. Additionally, when I draw, if I click on the markers, their information window pops up. How can I draw polygons on top of markers while preventing the marker information from being displayed?

I've tried using zIndex but it's not working.